# Angular 7: How to set default value on Reactive Form mat-select when value is an object with several IDs rather than a single ID?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I've looked at just about every other problem posed on this site and others and none cover trying to set the default to something a bit more complex than a single value.

I have a multi select that I want to show the selected for onload, comma separated.

```js
this.settingControls = new FormGroup({
  idsSelection: new FormControl(this.contentSettings.Ids)
});
```

```html
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of availIds" [value]="item.id">
      {{item | json}}
    </mat-option>
```

The list to select from has several fields, while the information I store and retrieve only has the Ids to make api calls smaller.

The list saved as `availIds` looks like so:

```
const availIds = [
{id: 1, name : "somename", childId: 1, childName: "somechildname"},
{id: 1, name : "somename", childId: 2, childName: "somechildname"},
{id: 2, name : "somename", childId: 1, childName: "somechildname"},
{id: 2, name : "somename", childId: 2, childName: "somechildname"}
```

Ok so, it used to be that I could pass in a single number array into `new FormControl()` (see above typescript code) and have value in the html be `[value]="item.id"`.  This would show, on load, the value selected, not the placeholder text. Ids loaded in would contain something like the following:

`this.contentSettings.Ids = [1, 2, 3];`

All as expected.

Now I want to store `{id: 1, childId: 1}` or `{'id': 1, 'childId': 1}` (it'll just be json on the db) and load that into the FormControl like so:

```js
this.settingControls = new FormGroup({
  idsSelection: new FormControl(this.contentSettings.Ids)
});
```

```html
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <mat-select multiple placeholder="Ids" formControlName="idsSelection">

  <!-- to check what value is actually being retrieved before it gets to typescript -->
  <!-- <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="idsSelection; let value">
      {{value | json}}
    </mat-select-trigger> -->

    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of availIds"
      [value]="{id: +item.id, childId: +item.childId}">
      {{item | json}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Loading in an object `{id: 1, childId: 1}` which is exactly what value contains when selecting an option does not make the default value `{id: 1, name : "somename", childId: 1, childName: "somechildname"}`which I need.

Can anyone shine some light on how this would be done? If it knows that a single number array being fed in is somehow mapped to id, then how can I get it to map the more complex object? It's definitely not done on reference because I previously just saved the ids in a number[].

Note: Just so everyone can see, I've added the json pipes to show that I've been watching the content of what the html thinks I've got as that has saved me in previous debugging sessions where I may have missed a + or quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the value set and saved to a primitive type so I changed [value] to be

```
value="{{item.id}}_{{item.childId}}">
```

then split it out again afterwards when I need to save it.

Comment: The reason for this was because primitive types are accepted while reference types simply aren't.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you set default values.

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <mat-select multiple placeholder="Ids" formControlName="idsSelection" [value]="your default value">

    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of availIds"
      [value]="{id: +item.id, channel: +item.channel}">
      {{item | json}}
    </mat-option>

  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now some case

If you set a value on the  you must set the same value on the default.

example

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of availIds"
  [value]="item.value">
  {{item | json}}
</mat-option>
```

then in your  you must use the same structure

```
<mat-select multiple placeholder="Ids" formControlName="idsSelection" [value]="availIds[0].value">
```

You can also specify the default value like this

```
this.settingControls = new FormGroup({ 
  idsSelection: new FormControl(THE_DEFAULT_OPTION, []) 
});
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. What would you put in ```this.settingControls = new FormGroup({
  idsSelection: new FormControl(???)
});``` then?

The documentation says that is where to put the default.

Comment: Did not work sorry. I added ```[value]="contentSettings.Ids"``` but it still shows the placeholder.

Comment: This is impossible, this must work 100%. the problem is you do not have the same data specified either on mat-select default input either on the mat-option value.

That's why you can't select a default value.

Comment: also, keep in mind that you convert the string to a number with the + plus on the front, so how you expect to set the default value??

Comment: I've thought of the + sign too. Removing the plus does not change the behaviour but ensures that the value extracted is a number. That has saved me in previous situations where the select was from an enum.

Where I would expect to put the default value is like your last example. but not even hard coding the value to something like ```idsSelection: new FormControl([{id: 1, childId: 1}])``` makes it work so I'm wondering if I've missed something. Maybe it expects id and channel to be in quotes? But I've already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Even if I take the whole object and load that in as the default, it still shows placeholder text.

```<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <mat-select multiple placeholder="Ids" formControlName="idsSelection" [value]="{id: 1, name :'somename', childId: 1, childName: 'somechildname'}">

    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of availIds" [value]="item">
      {{item | json}}
    </mat-option>

  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>```
 and 
```this.settingControls = new FormGroup({ 
  idsSelection: new FormControl({id: 1, name :'somename', childId: 1, childName: 'somechildname'}) 
});```

Comment: Worked it out. Will post answer soon.